# not selector, on() click event

Tags: jquery

I am having some problems in executing the following code:

```
    var i = 1;  
$('.hello:not(.selected)').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');       
    console.log(i++);   
});
```

The problem is that this code should trigger just ONE time after the class selected has added, but it is executing many times, I just want the *i* variable not to increase. In other words, I am trying to do the following (which works, but i don't want to use the live function since it has deprecated):

```
$('.hello:not(.selected)').live('click', function () { 
   $('.hello').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
... 
});
```

Thanks so much for your responses in advance,
k

Comment: Please explain in a bit more detail what is the expected behavior. What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: I think you forgot some additional code. Please explain

Comment: there is also the option of using [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your code is taking the set of elements that *currently* satisfy this criteria:

```
$('.hello:not(.selected)')
```

and setting up this event handler *for all eternity*:

```
.on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).css({opacity : 0.5});       
    console.log(i++);   
});
```

Particularly important is the fact that *once the handler is set on an element, it will continue to be active even if later on that element no longer satisfies the criteria* (in this case, by gaining the `selected` class).

There are several ways to achieve the desired behavior. One would be to dynamically check that the "filter" condition still holds inside the event handler:

```
$('.hello').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).css({opacity : 0.5});       
    console.log(i++);   
});
```

Another would be to delegate the event -- in this case, a parent element would be notified of the event on one of its descendants and it would *dynamically* check that said descendant satisfies the filter condition before deciding to trigger the event handler (code shamelessly pasted from Ben Lee's answer):

```
$('body').on('click', '.hello:not(.selected)', function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).css({opacity : 0.5});       
    console.log(i++);
});
```

Comment: I understand what you mean  by for all eternity, just wondering how this works : $('.tab:not(.active)').live('click', function () {, it is because of the live isnt it?, but isnt it setting up this event handler for all eternity as well, sorry but i am a little bit confused... but thanks soo much... because it works!

Comment: @ThePrincessKarina: Yes, `live` delegates the event and so ends up checking dynamically. That's how it can "attach a handler" to elements that do not even exist at the time you call `live`.

Comment: @Jon, hmm... Shamelessly paste my answer and get the accept for it. I should try that strategy ;). (really though, just joking around, your answer is equally correct and probably explains it better than mine)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is the event handler doesn't get removed just because you change the class. You are attaching the events to the elements, and they stay there forever.

To get around this, you could just test for the "selected" class on each event handle:

```
$('.hello:not(.selected)').on('click',function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).css({opacity : 0.5});       
        console.log(i++);
    }
});
```

But for efficiency and simpler code, you should probably delegate this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.hello:not(.selected)', function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.addClass('selected');
    $self.css({opacity : 0.5});       
    console.log(i++);
});
```

I used "body" as the element to attach this delegation, but you should probably use something lower in the tree, like a parent or grandparent of the ".hello" elements. This only attaches one event handler, and relies on bubbling to test the selected state of each element as they change in real time.

Also note that I cached `var $self = $(this)`; that was also for efficiency, so you don't end up jQuery-extending the element more than you need to.

Comment: Very nice it works... thanks very much for the advises on make my code more efficient. 
With my code I was trying to replicate the "$('.tab:not(.active)').live('click', function () { ", but using the "on", i guess I dont underestand very well the on, but this clarify ... THanks!