# How to NOT onclick in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I write the code for a NOT onlick event in JQuery?

I tried to go through the [NOT documentation for JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/not/) and also went through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478413/not-selector-on-click-event), but I was unable to find the answer.

This is what I tried:

```
$!('.form-submit').click(function() {
    // Do something when the form is NOT clicked.
});
```

Totally lost and unable to figure out the syntax to say when the submit button is NOT clicked.

Comment: Basically, I will set a timer for this and put this code inside that timer, so that when the timer hits say 5 seconds, it will check if the button is clicked. If its NOT clicked, I will do something and if its clicked I won't do anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize a timeout, and inside the click handler, clear the timeout:

```
const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('You did not click form-submit within 5 seconds');
}, 5000);

$('.form-submit').click(function() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

Comment: Thank you CertainPerformance, that did it! I am able to set my function inside that timer, and if the button is clicked, it clears that timer, thus, removing that function too. Exactly what I wanted.